# Setting a header on a Spring Weblux ServerResponse based on reactive content

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Spring 5's [ServerResponse.HeadersBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerResponse.HeadersBuilder.html#header-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) provides a `header(String, String)` method to add a header to the response in a reactive stack (using the [Functional Programming Model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC4/spring-framework-reference/reactive-web.html)).

The problem is that my header dependends on the content that I want to retrieve, something like:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getEntity(ServerRequest request) {
    String entityId = request.pathVariable("id");
    Mono<MyEntity> entity = service.findEntity(entityId);
    String headerValue = "???" // The header value depends on the values of the entity, which is not present at this point, here I only have access to the Mono 
    return ok().header("my-header", headerValue)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(entity , MyEntity.class);
  }
```

How can I specify a 'reactive' header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mapping out what you want the application to do

```
return service.findEntity(entityId).flatMap(entity -> {
    // Check entity and extract header the way you want

    return ok().header( ... );   
});
```